# Updating single package in old linux installation

Tags: linux, debian

I have this Raspberry Pi for which I compiled a kernel in order to get 1PPS support for the GPS signal.

I once did an `apt-get upgrade` on it and it replaced the kernel, so I had to restore it from a backup.

This device is the NTP server for the intranet, and I was wondering if I can selectively upgrade packages, ie **only** the `ntpd` to make sure that it is up to date.

On other devices, which I also haven't upgraded in a long time, because I'm afraid that they afterwards won't boot anymore (they are located remotely) I just installed new packages after doing an `apt-get update` without an `apt-get upgrade` (`git` and `molly-guard`), and everything seems to work without problems.

So my question is, can I safely upgrade just specific packages and leave the rest as-is, or will this cause problems? Also, can I just install new packages without upgrading the others?

On another device I am getting

> E: Release file for
>   http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease is expired
>   (invalid since 53d 13h 41min 46s). Updates for this repository will
>   not be applied.

How can I install new packages on that one by only making the absolute minimum change to the system?

Comment: Which model of the Raspberry Pi do you have exactly?  I presume since you used the *Debian* tag that is what you are running on the device?

Comment: First generation (Raspberry Pi 1 Model B). I compiled the kernel (3.12.18) on the 2014-05-09. Since then the device has not been upgraded. Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy

Answer (score 1):

In Debian generally, it's quite safe to just install or upgrade single packages, or a couple of packages, or however many you want, as long as the dependendencies are met. Dependency chains can get complicated, and sometimes the automatical resolving doesn't offer the best solution; in that case, `aptitude` really helps: The TUI needs a bit of acclimatisation, but you can easily explore different ways to resolve dependency issues.

Both `apt-get` and `aptitude` will show you what additional packages need to be installed (though only in `aptitude` you can easily change that if there are other ways), so it's easy to figure out the minimal change.

It's also in general not a problem to mix packages from different Debian releases, as long as you can figure out the dependencies. (I do that all the time).

Many Debian repositories have backports (though I'm not familiar with Raspian). Adding those repositories (matching the release you have mainly installed) will help with making minimal changes.

If the RaspPi is not connected to the Internet, you don't have to worry as much about missing security updates, either.